# Can't install TWRP to my Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite 5G NE (lisa)

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, xiaomi

Every time I try to install TWRP (or any other custom recovery) to my Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite 5G NE (lisa), I get these errors.

If I try `fastboot flash recovery TWRP.img`, I get this error:

```
Sending 'recovery' (196608 KB)                                             OKAY [  4.826s]
Writing 'recovery'                                        FAILED (remote: '(recovery_a) No such partition')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

And every time I try to boot into the recovery immediately: `fastboot boot TWRP.img`, it boots but the screen stays black.

Windows makes the connected sound, and if I check `adb devices`, it shows that the device is in recovery mode. But I can't see any recovery on my phone.

I tried it with 4 different custom recoveries and all of them gave the same errors/reactions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not an expert at all on partition and image flashing, but from the error `(recovery_a) No such partition`, looks like the recovery partition was deleted? Did you do something else before this issue started happening?

Comment: I don't believe that device has separate recovery partition at all